# If two points in a space are connected by a path, is there an injective map of an interval?

Tags: general-topology

I have difficulty coming up with a proof that if two points in a topological space $X$ are connected by a path, then there is an *injective* continuous map of $[0,1]$ to $X$ that sends $0$ and $1$ to those two points. Is this true? How is this proved?

---

Edit: As answered by Zev Chonoles, this is obviously false for general spaces. I would also like to have an answer for Hausdorff spaces.

---

Update: it turns out the hard part of this question is a duplicate of [A question about path-connected and arcwise-connected spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61868/a-question-about-path-connected-and-arcwise-connected-spaces)

Comment: General spaces? Hausdorff spaces? $T_1$ spaces?

Comment: As stated, i am asking about general spaces. In fact, i am more interested in Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 5):

Let $X=\{a,b\}$ with the topology $T=\{\varnothing,\{a\},X\}$ (which is non-Hausdorff). The map $f:[0,1]\to X$ defined by
$$f(t)=\begin{cases}
a & \text{ if }t\in [0,1),\\
b & \text{ if }t=1
\end{cases}$$
is continuous, but there is clearly no injective map from $[0,1]$ to $X$.

---

Your conjecture is true if we require $X$ to be Hausdorff. [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Arc_connectedness), a path-connected Hausdorff space is necessarily arc-connected. Thus, if $f:[0,1]\to X$ is the path from $a$ to $b$, the subspace $f([0,1])$ of $X$ is path-connected and Hausdorff, hence arc-connected, hence there is an arc connecting $a$ and $b$, which is in particular an injective continuous path $[0,1]\to X$.

Comment: Thanks, it was obvious! Excuse me for not accepting your answer because i am more interested in Hausdorff spaces, i am going to edit the question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to arc connected spaces, i forgot that those are different terms. I have also found that this question is a duplicate.  If i find somewhere a link to a proof, i will accept your answer, otherwise i am interested in a link to a proof.