# Unraveling a tangle

Tags: general-topology, continuity, curves

Let $f: [0,1] \to X$ be a continuous function from the segment $[0,1]$ to a Hausdorff space $X$ such that $f(0) \ne f(1)$.

Can we claim that there is always an **injective** continuous function $g: [0,1] \to X$ such that $g(0)=f(0)$ and $g(1)=f(1)$ ?

Comment: Does $g$ need to have any relation to $f$ other than at endpoints $0,1$?

Comment: @coffeemath No, only the properties listed above are mandatory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A question about path-connected and arcwise-connected spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61868/a-question-about-path-connected-and-arcwise-connected-spaces) (The definition of arcwise connectedness is every two distinct points can be connected by an injective path)