# Injective path in path-connected space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, path-connected

In any path-connected metric space, can we connect any two points with an injective path? This seems possible, for instance by "removing" the points where the loop is not injective, but I cannot prove it. Is it true? If yes, how to prove it? If not, do you have a counterexample?

Thank you very much,

AF

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61868/a-question-about-path-connected-and-arcwise-connected-spaces) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522642/does-path-connected-imply-simple-path-connected?noredirect=1&lq=1).